# Reduce SOAP runtime

Tags: database, soap, soap-api-v2

Either I'm doing sth. wrong or it's really slow here.
My script does:

1. Login/store session cookie
2. Fetch all orders `$client->salesOrderList($sessionId, $params);`
3. Fetch all attribute sets `$client->catalogProductAttributeSetList($sessionId);`
4. Iterate through the orders and fetch details `$client->salesOrderInfo ( $sessionId, $iOrderID );`
5. Iterate through each order and fetch the ordered items `$client->catalogProductInfo($sessionId, $id );`

So I guess the nested foreach are quite expensive.
I've got a shop with 1000 orders and like 30 products in avg per order.
WSDL caching is activated, so far I'm at 90% of fetching the data and it's running since two days.

Is there any chance I could reduce the whole thing to some minutes or do I need to look at getting the data directly from the Database? What's your impression? 2 days to like 30min possible or better shift the approach?